# Can you make Tor change servers every time I refresh a page?

Tags: onion-routing

I'm trying to build a bot but I need it that Tor will change servers every time I refresh the page. I could also use one if I get to manually change it using a command line. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say "change servers", do you mean change to a new circuit? Or do you mean change a specific node? For example, a new entry (guard) node, or a new exit node?

Comment: Which platform are you using? (Windows, Linux, Mac OS?)

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. I recommend using [Stem](https://stem.torproject.org/api/control.html) to control your tor circuit. Hopefully that points you in the right direction. The link also has a menu with [tutorials](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials.html) at the top that have some great examples to get used to using it. Good luck with your bot, I've made a few for Tor so I know it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use [stem](https://stem.torproject.org).

Assuming your Tor control port is 9051 and no cookie or password is needed, the following code will initialize a controller object.

```
import stem
import stem.control
controller=stem.control.Controller.from_port()
controller.authenticate()
```

Then, each time you want a new circuit, you can use

```
controller.signal(stem.Signal.NEWNYM)
```

By default, Tor will only establish a new circuit in this way at most every 10 seconds. If you want to have new circuits more frequently, you will need to changed the source code. `MAX_SIGNEWNYM_RATE` means the **interval** in seconds (although its name suggests the rate) at which it will accept the signal `NEWNYM`.